# Using a Swift 5.5 async variable in a SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, async-await, swiftui, swift5

In SwiftUI, I want to present a `List` however I want each of my screens/pages objects to own it's own title and image to be used in the `NavigationLink`.

So I have a protocol that each of my screens can use:

```
protocol DataScreen: View {
    var title: String { get async }
    var systemImage: String { get }
}
```

And I create some screens:

```
struct SystemInfoScreen: DataScreen {
    
    var title: String {
        get async {
            await Translator.shared.translate("sysInfo.title") ?? "System Information"
        }
    }
    
    var systemImage: String = "message"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("SystemInfoScreen")
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using an `async` function that looks up text in a file to return the correct title.

```
func translate(_ string:String?) async -> String? { ... }
```

The problem I am having, is using this `async` title in `SwiftUI`. I'm fairly new to `SwiftUI` but this is what I have so far:

```
struct SidebarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            CustomNavigationLink.navigationLink(screen: SystemInfoScreen())
        }
    }
}

struct CustomNavigationLink {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    static func navigationLink<S>(screen:S) -> some View where S: DataScreen {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: screen,
            label: {
                Label(screen.title, systemImage: screen.systemImage )
            })
    }
}
```

This gives an error on `screen.title`:

> 'async' property access in a function that does not support
> concurrency

I kind of wasn't expecting that to work as is, but is it possible to use this `async var` in this way?

Comment: Why is the `Translator` class loading the translations in an async manner? That will not provide a good UX, as the texts on the screen will seem to randomly change based on the duration of the async operations. Also,  what are you planning to display until the async task finishes?

Comment: The translator uses the new async line by line reading of a file to find the right translation. I guess it will just display nothing until it's found, but it really wouldn't take that long.

Comment: `wouldn't take long` - this is an assumption about the implementation, which later on can change and something that currently takes 20ms, it might later on take 20s. If you're sure it's fast, then you can use the synchronous version. Either that, or create a model (ObservableObject), and use the async operation to update a published property there.

Comment: And to answer the question from the last paragraph, no, you cannot pass an async result to a synchronous context, like SwiftUI. The async result might very well also come on a different thread, which will break SwiftUI, as UI components are not thread safe.